# SVGs are showing inverted colors in Safari and Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, svg, safari

I am building out a knowledge base at work using Docusaurus. I've uploaded some SVGs to the main page, but Safari will view the Office Logo SVG incorrectly but the Ministry Platform logo correctly.

Chrome switches the two. It displays Office correctly, but the Ministry Platform logo is incorrect.

[Safari Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFnE8.png)

It's very strange. I'm not sure why Chrome and Safari show them differently. I don't know a lot about SVGs though.

Here is the code for the React component:

````
    ```import React from 'react';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import styles from './HomepageFeatures.module.css';


const FeatureList = [
  {
    title: 'About Perimeter',
    Svg: require('../../static/img/perlogonew.svg').default,
    description: (
      <>
        Get refreshed on our Values, Vision, and Mission.
      </>
    ),
  },
  {
    title: 'Microsoft Office',
    Svg: require('../../static/img/officeicon.svg').default,
    description: (
      <>
        Learn more about Teams, Outlook, Planner, and ToDo.
      </>
    ),
  },
  {
    title: 'Ministry Platform',
    Svg: require('../../static/img/mplogo.svg').default,
    description: (
      <>
        Learn more about how to use templates, groups, events, and more in Ministry Platform.
      </>
    ),
  },
];

   function Feature({Svg, title, description}) {
  return (
    <div className={clsx('col col--4')}>
      <div className="text--center">
        <Svg className={styles.featureSvg} alt={title} />
      </div>
      <div className="text--center padding-horiz--md">
        <h3>{title}</h3>
        <p>{description}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function HomepageFeatures() {
  return (
    <section className={styles.features}>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          {FeatureList.map((props, idx) => (
            <Feature key={idx} {...props} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
     );
    }
````

Comment: have you duplicated id values and/or class names between the two so they interfere with each other?

Comment: Are you asking if I did that accidentally or suggesting that I do that?

Comment: I'm asking if you did that accidentally as it's likely the cause of your problem.

Comment: Hi, did You found solution to this problem yet? Wondering because i have same problem now.